# Xcode 4 configure to use less RAM?

Tags: memory, xcode4

I've been trying to use Xcode 4 on my 1GB Mac Mini.  It's not a happy situation.  It frequently slows way down, presumably due to memory shortages.

Are there any settings I can change so it won't be such a memory hog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing the following.  None of them reduced Xcode's memory consumption, but they did reduce the memory needed by other programs, and hence solved my problem -- speed is fine now.

- Start using chrome instead of Firefox
- Turn off spotlight and dashboard
- Don't auto-launch iTunes

Answer (score 3):

Another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929718/xcode-suddenly-very-slow) suggests that the problem may be having the "predictive compilation turned on in the Xcode preferences."