# Minimum spec for Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

So after deciding to install Xcode 4 on my '09 mac mini because of how useful its instruments feature is (opengl stuff), it turns out that my mac mini only barely manages to run it.

In other words, it's crippled. I'm still here waiting for my program to run on the iPhone, and it's stuck with some "NSAutoreleaseNoPool" message.

The thing is, normally I would ask on how to fix that message, but currently XCode itself is frozen and not responding to anything.

Will upgrading from this old mac mini (it only has 1GB ram) alleviate this issue? Would the new mac mini with a 4GB ram upgrade suffice? IIRC it's core 2 duo 2.25ghz as opposed to my current 1.83ghz, would that make enough difference?

edit: not to mention, indexing cripples the performance to an extreme level

Comment: You can use the new Instruments from Xcode 4 and stick with Xcode 3.2.6 for development until you can get a higher spec machine.

Comment: With 1G RAM you are almost certainly swapping, and an anemic hard drive makes it worse (5400 RPM if I'm not mistaken).  Add RAM if you can.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5642804/240633

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Especially when dealing with running VMs (i.e. an iPhone/iOS emulator), RAM is usually the choke point in my past experience.

I would think 4 Gigs of RAM should do it just fine. My Mac Book Pro has 4 Gigs of RAM and runs android emulators all the time and I'm still able to multitask.

Go into an Apple store and tell the guy you wanna demo the latest gen Mac Mini running XCode and its emulators and see if the performance if worth the investment. Its all Apple hardware/software so I don't see why they can't help you out.

Comment: And please tell us the result. Because I wonder the same thing :-)

Answer (score 0):

**8GB Ram**

Since you can get already even 16GB Ram in Mac Mini (at least the newest), I cannot see why not take it? More [here](http://www.apple.com/fi/mac-mini/specs.html). Related threads mention very painful experiences with 1/2/4Gt particularly with Xcode 4. As far as I see it, 8Gt is becoming really a must-have, particularly when Xcode turns to 5.

**Xcode 4 experiences**

- [Minimum spec for Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116504/minimum-spec-for-xcode-4)
- http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/303406-xcode-4-system-requirement.html
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14923/what-is-the-minimum-hardware-needed-to-run-xcode-4

**Similar gettings slow threads**

- [Xcode 4 configure to use less RAM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642804/xcode-4-configure-to-use-less-ram)
- [Xcode suddenly very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929718/xcode-suddenly-very-slow)