# Xcode runs slowly and hogs CPU

Tags: xcode, performance, memory, cpu

Lots of times Xcode (seemingly randomly) starts to run extremely slowly- it can take around fifteen seconds to move an object in IB, or compiling after changing one line of code can still take up to ten seconds. I took a look at my Activity Monitor, and this is what I found:

[image: Xcode - 115.4%?]

My question is, is this normal?

Comment: Look here
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355667/xcode-4-slow-performance][1]
and here
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929718/xcode-suddenly-very-slow][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929718/xcode-suddenly-very-slow
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929718/xcode-suddenly-very-slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have 2GB's of RAM. With each update to Apple's software, they get more memory intensive. The same goes with Safari 5.1+. So to answer your question, Yes, this is normal for a machine with 2GB's of RAM running Lion as well as other memory intensive applications, Chrome being another.

As for Interface Builder, I have noticed this too. XIB's are XML files, so I believe as you move an object, Interface Builder is writing it's location on the view as it is moved, so that is a very data heavy task as well.

Comment: Nice to know I'm not the only one. Should have a new MBP coming with 8 GB RAM and the new quad-core i7- that'll fix it!

Answer (score 2):

2GB of RAM is way more than enough, even for latest versions of Xcode.

Looks like you've hit one of the bugs in Xcode compilation / indexing / syntax hilighting. c.f.: [Xcode 4.3.2 and 100% CPU constantly in the idle time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522936/xcode-4-3-2-and-100-cpu-constantly-in-the-idle-time)

Answer (score 0):

XCode is usually around 20-30% CPU sitting in the background doing nothing. It's a pig that's all.